# How to reusing tikz pictures from thesis in beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, ieeetran

This is a general question. While writing a paper/thesis, I am making my block diagrams, each in a separate files e.g fig1.tex, using tikz and then include it in my document using \input{fig1}.

For making presentation I am using same figure so therefore I reuse fig1.tex. But I need to use features likes highlighting blocks, changing colors of lines/arrows for animation purposes. If I have had made figure from scratch for my presentation, I could do have done that easily but I don't understand how to do this when I am reusing fig1.tex that has no such thing?

Comment: Edit `fig1.tex`? How else would you do it? Maybe I don't understand the kind of example you have in mind, but how else can you specify things in the figure?

Comment: Actually I was thinking to add a layer on top of fig1.tex after including it in my frame but that would be more messy.

Comment: You need to provide a minimal working example.

Comment: Note that it is much easier the other way around i.e. Beamer -> article or whatever.